# Flag for my own reference?

Tags: support, feature-request, specific-question

Not sure if this is the best place to ask this but I'll ask :)

Is it possible to flag questions for your own reference? Not the star thing.

What I'd like to do is be able to flag a question that I have no clue how to answer so I can continue helping answer questions I have a clue about.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. If I want to flag a question that I want to remember to answer later (or research answers for), I use the star. You can see all questions you have starred by visiting your profile page and clicking Favorites (e.g. mine is [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/150/adrian-macneil?tab=favorites)).

If you want to "hide" the question, there's no way to do that I'm aware of. You can use the "ignored tags" feature if for example there is a particular topic you know nothing about which gets lots of questions (e.g. stash, assets). However, it's much easier to just follow the tags you DO know about.

Comment: Stars are the opposite of what I want to do. I want to filter out stuff I know for sure I can't answer. The biggest help this would be is if I want to be sure to go through and answer "unanswered" questions. Without being able to clear out things I don't know I always end up with a slew on top that I have to navigate through.


Following tags you do know would be overwhelming, not easier IMHO. For instance I'd love to follow add-on development but if something pops up about the Structure add-on I don't really know anything about Structure nor care to use it.

Comment: Well, don't feel obliged to look at and either answer or "clear out" every single question :) Generally I open the site each day, scroll down the home page and unanswered questions list, and open any in a new tab that interest me. We don't really have any control over the platform here, we can only help you figure out how best to use it.

Comment: @eedfwChris For what you're describing, I would suggest explicitly ignoring `Structure` tagged questions.

Comment: I think this would be a great addition for people consistently answering questions. It can all seem overwhelming after awhile so being able to "dim" questions individually instead of with ignore tags would be awesome!

Comment: You have to remember though that this platform is designed for Stack Overflow which gets [7,300 questions per day](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic). So in that context, no one is ever going to be at a point where they are dimming/hiding questions they have dealt with. That said, there is always the CSS `a:visited` color which we do have control over once we leave beta.